# Domain and range of two-variable function with square root

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the following function: $f(x,y) = -\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$.
I calculated its domain as $\{x, y \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 9 \}$
but then when I was calculating the range I got confused by this:

if $x$ and $y$ are powered by $2$ then into the radicant I can only subtract, leading me to think that the greater value of the range it's detemined by: $-\sqrt{9}$

my main question is... Why I can't pick here the negative value of the square root and proceed as $-(-3) = 3$ ? Because I checked the answer and in fact is $Range \: f: \: [-3, 0]$

I know it will be such a noob concept missing or something like that, thanks in advance.

Comment: @user251257 oh, yes, I'll try to edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question the person who wrote the question has already "chosen" the sign of the root. So, when a question says $x=\sqrt4$ the value is the positive root which is 2.

This is different from when you have something like $x^2=4$ where you have to take the square root, then both -2 and 2 are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sqrt{x}$ is never a negative number. The symbol by definition is nonnegative. The negative root is denoted by $-\sqrt{x}$.

It is true that a positive number $x$ has two "square roots", $\pm\sqrt{x}$. But be very clear about this -- "the" square root refers to the *positive* root. Don't make the mistake of thinking that $\sqrt{x}$ has two values or that it can be positive or negative. Specifically: $\sqrt{9}$ is the number $3$; it is definitely *not* the number $-3$.

Admittedly, the terminology is ambiguous at times.